# How can i fix this problem with index builder using binary search tree?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I've an assignment which is to write an index builder application , which takes text consisting of lines and prints a list of the words of the text and the lines they appear on are printed next to them.

but i faced a problem when i tried to handle the case if the word already exist , it's always add a redundant number to the vector

can anyone help me please?

This is the definition of the BSTnode:

```
class BSTnode
{
public:
    string data;
    vector<int> linesAppear;
    BSTnode* left;
    BSTnode* right;
    BSTnode()
    {
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};
```

This is the definition of the BSTFCI:

```
class BSTFCI
{
public:
    BSTnode* root;
    BSTFCI()
    {
        root = NULL;
    }
    void add(string ToBST,int lineAppear);
    BSTnode* Insert(BSTnode*& node,string ToBST,int lineAppear);
    BSTnode* create_new_node(string ToBST,int lineAppear);   
};
```

The functions for insert

```
BSTnode* BSTFCI::create_new_node(string ToBST,int lineAppear)
{
    BSTnode* Temp = new BSTnode();
    Temp->data = ToBST;
    Temp->left = Temp->right = NULL;
    Temp->linesAppear.push_back(lineAppear);
    return Temp;
}
BSTnode* BSTFCI::Insert(BSTnode*& node,string ToBST,int lineAppear)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        node = create_new_node(ToBST,lineAppear);
    }
    if(ToBST > node->data)
    {
        node->right = Insert(node->right,ToBST,lineAppear);
    }
    if(ToBST < node->data)
    {
        node->left = Insert(node->left,ToBST,lineAppear);
    }
    //cout <<"inside insert"<< ToBST << endl;
    if(node->data == ToBST)
    {
        node->linesAppear.push_back(lineAppear);
     //   cout <<"inside insert condition "<< node->data << endl;
    }
    return node;

}
void BSTFCI::add(string ToBST,int lineAppear)
{
    root = Insert(root,ToBST,lineAppear);
}
```

the main function:

```
int main()
{
    BSTFCI o;
    string input,ToBST;
    int lineAppear = 0;
    while(getline(cin,input))
    {
        if(input == "done")
        {
            break;
        }
        lineAppear++;
        istringstream convert(input);
        while(convert >> ToBST)
        {
            o.add(ToBST,lineAppear);
        }
    }
    o.print_inOrder(o.root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without you showing us your code (in [mcve] form). We cannot possibly help you.

Comment: i'm really sorry for this , it's unintentional

Comment: i've modified the post

Answer (score 0):

It's because you add the number both in `create_new_node` (which should be a constructor in `BSTnode`, really) *and* later, when `if(node->data == ToBST)`.

You need to decide whether to add it when creating a node or afterwards, but doing it on creation makes the most sense – why would you add a node without also giving it an occurrence?

I would do like this:

```
class BSTnode
{
public:
    string data;
    vector<int> linesAppear;
    BSTnode* left;
    BSTnode* right;
    BSTnode() : left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    BSTnode(const std::string& word, int appearance) 
        : data(word),
          linesAppear(1, appearance),
          left(nullptr),
          right(nullptr)
    {
    }
};


BSTnode* BSTFCI::Insert(BSTnode* node, string ToBST,int lineAppear)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
    {
        return new BSTnode(ToBST, lineAppear);
    }
    if(ToBST > node->data)
    {
        node->right = Insert(node->right, ToBST, lineAppear);
    }
    else if(ToBST < node->data)
    {
        node->left = Insert(node->left, ToBST, lineAppear);
    }
    else
    {
        node->linesAppear.push_back(lineAppear);
    }
    return node;
}
```

Note that there is no point in both passing `node` by reference *and* returning it, so I kept the returning and removed the reference.
You could also do the opposite.

Comment: what is the meaning of this line ```linesAppear(1, appearance)```

Comment: It initialises the vector with one element whose value is `appearance`. It uses constructor number 2 on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: @Omar_Ashraf99 If you don't initialise it with any elements, it does. (It's usually a better idea to create things in their desired state than to create them in a default state and modify it afterwards.)